# Writing a conditional to add an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add an attribute to an element that is called dynamically using the select2 jQuery library.

When the page is open a `span` element is added with a class of `select2-container`, I need to add a unique `data-bactmln` attribute value to each `span` element with the `select2-container` class.

Since the `span` is nested in a `div` and each `div` is set up as such:

```
<div class="fieldset cr">
   ...
   <span class="select2-container"></span>
</div>
```

can I target the `span` in that `div` to add the specific attribute value?

I tried using a conditional, however I'm having trouble getting it to work.

```
if($('.cr')){
  $('.select2-container').attr('data-bactmln', 'CR_FeaturesDropdown');
}
```

Comment: `$('span').hasClass('select2-container').attr('data-bactmln', 'CR_FeaturesDropdown');` Now you just need to figure out when the right time to run this code should be, otherwise it'll initialize on DOM ready. You could wrap it in a `.bind()` function `$(window).bind('load', function{});` which will run after page load, but may not be consistent.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError `hasClass()` is not a filter method...it returns a boolean and `bind()` is deprecated

Comment: @charlietfl Oh snap! You're very right about that.

Comment: Doesn't `$('.select2-container span').attr('data-bactmln', 'CR_FeaturesDropdown');` work?

Comment: `if($('.cr'))` is always truthy since jQuery returns an object

Comment: My guess is you are reading it before the element is rendered. `console.log($('.select2-container').length ? "I am here" : "I am not here")`

Comment: @Andy no that does not work. I am not seeing the attribute added the the span.

Comment: @scrippyfingers. I don't know why not. [Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/t6nog3t7/1/) that uses a timeout to add the HTML to the `cr` div after two seconds to mimic what you're doing, and then adds the data attributes to the inner spans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change your condition to

```
if($('.cr').length > 0){
  $('.select2-container').attr('data-bactmln', 'CR_FeaturesDropdown');
}
```

if `$('.cr')` has a value it its length will be bigger than 0

```js
if($('.cr').length > 0){
  $('.select2-container').attr('data-bactmln', 'CR_FeaturesDropdown');
  console.log($('.select2-container').data());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fieldset cr">
   ...
   <span class="select2-container"></span>
</div>
```